# django migration set default not working

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django version 1.8.3 and mysql version 5.6.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL).

I have been trying to implement database for user-login as shown below.

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

but when I do `manage.py migrate` on this, I get

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE `login_user` ALTER COLUMN `is_active` SET DEFAULT 1;
ALTER TABLE `login_user` ALTER COLUMN `is_active` DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE `login_user` ALTER COLUMN `is_admin` SET DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE `login_user` ALTER COLUMN `is_admin` DROP DEFAULT;
COMMIT;
```

I don't understand why it sets default value and then drops it.
Can anyone enlighten me what is going on here?

Thank you.

edit: I've added my migrations file.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='User',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
            ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=50)),
            ('password', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('is_active', models.BooleanField()),
            ('is_admin', models.BooleanField()),
            ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ('num_friends', models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()),
            ('bio', models.CharField(max_length=150)),
            ('my_photo', models.ImageField(upload_to=b'profile')),
        ],
        options={
        },
        bases=(models.Model,),
    ),
]

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('login', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='user',
        name='is_active',
        field=models.BooleanField(default=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='user',
        name='is_admin',
        field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
    ),
]


mysql> desc login_user;
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name  | varchar(50)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name   | varchar(50)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(50)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(50)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active   | tinyint(1)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_admin    | tinyint(1)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime(6)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| num_friends | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bio         | varchar(150)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| my_photo    | varchar(100)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you show the migration file created by Django?

Comment: @Alasdair Yap. I just added one.

Comment: Note that Django doesn't set the default in SQL (see [ticket 470](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470)). Having said that,  I can't explain why the migration is setting the default and then removing it.

Comment: @Alasdair  thank you for your response. So what you mean is specifying default value in django models don't do anything? If so, how shall I go about solving this problem?

Comment: No, I don't mean that defaults don't do anything. The default value is used by Django, but it doesn't update the schema. Remember, the default can be a callable, which means it might be impossible to set it in the schema. If you only create objects using the orm, then maybe you shouldn't worry about the default. If you really need the default in the schema, then you'll need to set it some other way (manual migration or manually enter the SQL statement to set the default).

Comment: But this is stupidity from django.If there are multiple application using the same db and django is unable to create default.How the system be stable.Their ORM is not also a great piece of work.

Comment: I think this is a designed feature that migration would generate "DROP DEFAULT" SQL even if there's not db changes as is discussed in these tickes: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23581 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470